# Gmail search query: messages in inbox with any user label

Tags: gmail

I'd like to quickly select all messages in my inbox that already have a label so I can archive them, but I'm struggling to create a robust search query, something like:

> in:inbox AND has:anyuserlabel

is what I'm after (but of course that doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

And of course after hours of trying, I find the answer just after posting my question:

> in:inbox AND has:userlabels